# Hierarchical menu nesting problem with jQuery targetting

Tags: menus, jquery, sub-menu

(Wordpress's menu use the form

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children"> Item
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li> Sub Menu Item</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</li>
...
```

which means that any click event on a sub menu item is also a click on the parent item. ( It also means that any styles like `background-color` affect also the enclosed children but that's easy to resolve)

I want to target (in this example) `$('.sub-menu')` without the click event affecting the enclosing `.menu-item-has-children` so that I can treat a click on the outer 'Item' differently to the inner 'Sub Menu Item'.

So far I have not been able to do this.

Comment: try that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164213/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-on-checkbox-click#answer-1164254